# Определить макимальное количество запросов в секунду

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Главная цель. Определить максимальное количество запросов к приложению в секунду.
Есть приложение django. Каждый запрос записывается в базу. Мне нужно определить максимальное количество запросов в секунду.
Помогите составить запрос или написать правильный скрипт для management/commands

P.S.: В общем помог с этим ChatGPT)) Если кому вдруг пригодится, запрос такой:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncSecond
from django.db.models import Count

max_count = MyModel.objects.annotate(second=TruncSecond('created')).values('second').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('-count').first()['count']
```

Comment: Что именно записывается в базу? Какая структура таблицы? Что вы понимаете под "максимальным числом запросов в секунду"? Последний вопрос вообще принципиальный. Выражение "число ... в секунду" означает какое-то среднее (для которого потом отыскивается максимум). О каком среднем речь? Среднее за секунду? За минуту? За час? За сутки?

Comment: Да сама структура в вопросе не важна. Допустим id | user_id | title | created_at. Запись создаётся при каждом обращении. Если простыми словами, то нужно определить максимальное количество обращений сделанных в интервале 1ой секунды. Т.е. максимальную нагрузку в секунду.